# Do any one know how to draw high chart in Extjs ? Do you i need any plug-in for this

Tags: extjs4

Do i need a plug in for high chart. I have searched through the net can anyone give me a solution. I have found that a plug in is needed for the Extjs 3 but what about version 4 onwards

Answer (score 1):

It will require extension.  However, it appears that an extension is already available on [github](https://github.com/JoeKuan/Highcharts_Sencha/).  Additionally, charting in ExtJS4 is supported so if you don't need highcharts specifically then the chart you require may already be supported.  Charting examples with native ExtJS are available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example).

Comment: Thank you so much weeksdev. I am sure that there are several chart options already in Extjs4 but they have so many issues too as per my requirement that's why i went for looking high chart. That link is useful.